# Listening for received chat event

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I am fairly new to Firebase as well as angular2. So I am trying to make a Firebase integrated angular2 Chat app through tutorials. I have followed  [this tutorial](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/31/How-to-Make-an-Angular-Firebase-Chat-App)  to make the chat app. The problem is that addition to the simple chat, I want to create a toast when someone writes or receives a new chat. But I can't seem to find the code where I can listen to the that event.

Any idea where do I find it?

angular component looks something like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  name: any;
  msgVal: string = '';

    constructor(public af: AngularFire) {

        this.items = af.database.list('/messages', {
          query: {
            limitToLast: 5
          }
        });

        this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => { 
          if(auth) {
            this.name = auth;
          }
        });
    }

login() {
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup,
    });
  }

chatSend(theirMessage: string) {
      this.items.push({ message: theirMessage, name: this.name.facebook.displayName});
       this.msgVal = '';
  }
}
```

and this is the html markup

```
<div class="row columns">
  <button (click)="login()" *ngIf="!name">Login With Facebook</button>

  <input type="text" id="message" *ngIf="name" placeholder="Chat here..." (keyup.enter)="chatSend($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="msgVal" />

    <div class="chat-container" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
      <a href="#">{{item.name}}</a>

      <p>{{item.message}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the Gentlement from reddit helped me and told to check for FirebaseObservables and listen for changes on it.

```
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
database().ref().on('value', function(snapshot){

  var x = snapshot.val()
  console.log("This prints whenever there is a new message");
});
```

this snippet inside the main module triggers whenever there are any new messages in the chat thread.

Hope it helps someone